Pico & ESP32 & NRF24L01 Communications problem
I want to communicate with pico and esp32 via nrf24l01.
I used the following library to communicate between two picos and it worked:
https://github.com/AndyRids/pico-nrf24/tree/main
I was able to run nrf24l01 between two esp32 modules.
But I could not establish communication between pico and esp32 via nrf24l01.
I am using esp32 c3 devkit m1.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Esp32 main.cpp
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(8, 7, 5000000);  // CE CSN

uint8_t weight = 5;

const byte address[5] = {0x37, 0x37, 0x37, 0x37, 0x37};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    delay(2000);
    if (!radio.begin()) {
        Serial.println(F("Radio hardware not responding!"));
    }
    radio.setChannel(50);
    radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
    radio.setPayloadSize(1);
    radio.enableAckPayload();
    radio.enableDynamicAck();
    radio.setRetries(3, 10);
    radio.setAddressWidth(5);
    radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
    radio.startListening();
}
uint32_t sendTimer = 0;

void loop() {
    if (radio.available()) {
        radio.read(&weight, 1);
        Serial.println(weight);
    }
}

Pico main.c
int main() {
    stdio_init_all();

    pin_manager_t my_pins = {.sck = 2, .copi = 3, .cipo = 4, .csn = 5, .ce = 6};

    nrf_manager_t my_config = {.channel = 50,
                               .address_width = AW_5_BYTES,
                               .dyn_payloads = DYNPD_ENABLE,
                               .data_rate = RF_DR_1MBPS,
                               .power = RF_PWR_NEG_12DBM,
                               .retr_count = ARC_10RT,
                               .retr_delay = ARD_500US};

    uint32_t my_baudrate = 5000000;

    nrf_client_t my_nrf;

    nrf_driver_create_client(&my_nrf);

    my_nrf.configure(&my_pins, my_baudrate);
    my_nrf.initialise(&my_config);
    my_nrf.payload_size(ALL_DATA_PIPES, 1);
    my_nrf.standby_mode();
    uint8_t payload_zero = 123;

    fn_status_t success = 0;

    uint64_t time_sent = 0;  // time packet was sent
    uint64_t time_reply = 0;  // response time after packet sent

    while (1) {
        my_nrf.tx_destination((uint8_t[]){0x37, 0x37, 0x37, 0x37, 0x37});
        time_sent = to_us_since_boot(get_absolute_time());  // time sent
        success = my_nrf.send_packet(&payload_zero, sizeof(payload_zero));
        time_reply = to_us_since_boot(get_absolute_time());  // response time
        if (success) {
            printf("\nPacket sent:- Response: %lluμS | Payload: %d\n",
                   time_reply - time_sent, payload_zero);
        } else {
            printf("\nPacket not sent:- Receiver not available.\n");
        }
        sleep_ms(3000);
    }
}

I tried to make sure that all settings were the same in both, but there must be something I missed.

The RF signals are very sensitive to power supply noise. Do you have decoupling capacitors across the power inputs to each board? 10uF to 100uF are fine. Have you tried a lower baud rate? I don't have a nrf24l01 to test with, these are just general troubleshooting ideas to try.
